# Is it OK to eat non-certified-as-kosher sushi?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher

I've heard the argument that since everything in sushi is raw (assuming there are no non-kosher ingredients), and that since the rice is cooked in a rice cooker that is used only for rice, it's OK to eat. Is this true?

Comment: Sean, thanks for the interesting question, and welcome to the site; I hope you stick around and enjoy it. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your [account](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1385), which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557) to more of the site's features.

Comment: What does pretty have to do with the question? You must mean seemingly frum.

Comment: Well, the fact that some sushi fauna are nonkosher would give me concern. Also I don't know if "so many pretty frum people" is grounds for a question; do you know if any rav rules that it is allowed? What [type of] community are we dealing with?

Comment: @GershonGold - I'm pretty sure he meant "pretty" as an adjective describing "frum," not describing the "people" in question. (But I must admit that at first it threw me off too!) I edited the question to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: Related: [Is shashimi at a non-kosher restaurant kosher?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14686/1172).

Comment: Further edited, @yitznewton. Hopefully this will clear up the questions on the question.

Comment: Why wouldn't the rice be bishul akum?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This article](http://www.crcweb.org/kosher_articles/kosher_sushi.php) by the CRC discusses this issue at length.

In short, the answer is: **No**, it is not okay to eat non-certified sushi. See the article for details, but some of the problems include:

- The sides, such as wasabi, soy sauce, and pickled ginger are suspect (for artificial coloring, manufacture with non-kosher products, and utensils used with *davar charif* respectively, along with other concerns).
- Cooked rice requires *bishul yisrael*, which must be certified.
- There is a possibility (albeit unlikely) that a certain type of seaweed paper for which bug-infestation is common, was used.
- The fish may have been soaked in brine to preserve color and flavor.

Answer (score 5):

Per the [CRC-Chicago](http://www.crcweb.org/kosher_articles/kosher_sushi.php).

> There are various halachik questions in relation to Sushi and why you
>   may not buy even raw Sushi from a non-certified establishment.

Comment: You beat me to it by one minute!