# Fresh fish need hechsher

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification, fish

Does fresh fish from a supermarket or fish market require a hechsher? I would be tempted to believe that a fish known to be of a kosher variety would not need certification since there is no shechita or cooking involved. Is this correct?

As a follow-up: What about packaged fish? What if the fish is cut?

Comment: There is an issue that we do not rely that fish flesh that we see on the shelf is from a Kosher fish, even if we believe it is and the store labels it as such (like salmon). I believe this was discussed somewhere on this site, but I don't know where. If you can see the fins and scales, though, you are ok in principle, so long as you clean it properly ([Kelipah](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14811/5), for example).

Comment: @SethJ What if it's cut?

Comment: http://oukosher.org/index.php/common/article/1386301

Comment: @doubleAA Thanks! I tried searching the OU website, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: @SethJ IIRC, salmon is actually the exception. (and the OU link confirms: "and we still endorse the idea of buying skinless salmon")

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, I apologize. I was just trying to help out the OP with additional information. Could'a picked a better example.

Comment: Closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14686

Comment: @SethJ no worries!  just don't want to leave that around unresponded to.

Comment: What did they do before the business of hechsherim when it came to buying and eating fish. That's your answer.

Comment: @Yehoshua That's no answer. There weren't always business doing hechsherim. Does that mean that _no_ food needs reliable hashgacha?

Comment: related: [Certified vs. Uncertified Costco Salmon](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/107011/certified-vs-uncertified-costco-salmon)

Answer (score 4):

IIRC, I heard from R. Nota Greenblatt, that if one can successfully identify the fish as a kosher species, it is permitted.

If it has been cut with a knife that be non-kosher, then the area of the cut should be washed out.

Similarly, KosherQuest (operated by R. E. Eidlitz) [here](http://www.kosherquest.org/getfood.php?id=2101) states that fresh fish with fins and scales needs no hechsher.

Answer (score 2):

If the fish is labeled as a kosher species, even if it's cut, it is permitted per Rabbi Yitzchak Abadi if you wash the fish. Even if your kosher fish is next to shrimp or other unkosher species, it is still permitted.

Source: http://kashrut.org/forum/viewpost.asp?mid=3996&highlight=shrimp

Comment: Rav Abadi is very, very lenient on kashrus; way more than the mainstream. YMMV

Comment: @SAH My experience is that he generally follows classical Jewish sources. most authorities are very very stringent on kashrut. Regardless, I am not sure why your previous comment is relevant.