# PTIJ: Is my mask posul?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

When I was wearing my mask, one of the strings snapped, I then typed the two ends together and reapplied.

The Rambam writes (Malve 23:14):

> נקרע קרע בית דין הרי זה פסול איזהו קרע בית דין שתי וערב
>
> If it was torn with a based-in tear, it is invalid. What is a based-in tear? Drink and enjoy!

I guess I’m having trouble getting to the depth of his intention.
Did I still fulfill my obligation, or must I put on another mask?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not only is your mask possul, it is in fact a d'orayta commandment never to have anything to do with a mask! See Shemot 34:17, https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.34?lang=bi&aliyot=0

"מַסֵּכָ֖ה לֹ֥א תַעֲשֶׂה־לָּֽךְ"

"You shall not make a mask for yourself"

Comment: Is my mask בטל in my scarfs, then

Comment: Sorry, @Dr. Shmuel, I'd love to find grounds for leniency, but if you look up מסכה in Jastrow, you'll find it means "idol; molten image" and, as you know, Avodah Zarah is not בטל no matter what the ratio

Comment: That mitzva is only that you have to get a mask from someone else. See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6432/is-wearing-masks-on-purim-a-biblical-commandment-or-a-rabbinic-commandment/6433#6433

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations! You are זוכה in a סיום מסכת.

So you should have a (socially distanced) celebration!

As we learn from the text of Hadran, it is always permitted to return to Torah you have learned. So there was no problem in wearing it.